# How can two different strings match?

Tags: php, string, comparison

I test the input of a form against values in the data base. When it comes to the fax and phone numbers the string comparison fails.

```
$fax = trim($args['fax']);
$oldFax = trim($address->getFax());
if($fax != $oldFax){
  $address->setFax($fax);
  $address->flagChanged('fax');
}
```

The above test finds a match when comparing "+494321" with "00494321". Why is that? If I test using !== instead it works as expected.

Comment: When you use `!=` or `==`, strings are converted to numbers if they look like numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of [type juggling](http://php.net/juggling), which means that [strings can be used as numbers](http://php.net/types.string#language.types.string.conversion), and that you are using the "loosely equal to" [comparison operator](http://php.net/operators.comparison#language.operators.comparison) `==`.

If an operand of an expression is a *number* (i.e. contains digits and can be thought of as *a number*) then it will be converted to the appropriate number type (`integer` or `float`) before being compared. So, this is how PHP actually sees the following expression:

```
("+494321" == "00494321") => (494321 == 494321)
```

The first operand has the plus sign removed (it just means that the number is positive), and the second operand has the zeros truncated (they do not really mean anything; i.e. `07` and `7` are both the same decimal number, just represented slightly differently).

If you want to compare two strings *exactly* then there are a few ways to do it. The first is to simply use the "exactly equal to" operator `===`. Using this operator, operands will never be type juggled, which is to say that both sides of the comparison operator will be matches exactly; strings will be strings, integers will be integers, and so on.

As an example, these two expressions will both be equal to `false`:

```
"123" === 123
"006" === 6
```

Another way is to use the [`strcmp`](http://php.net/strcmp) function (or similar related functions). It compares strings byte by byte:

```
$a = "+494321";
$b = "00494321";
if (strcmp($a, $b) === 0) {
    echo "The same";
} else {
    echo "Not the same";
}
```

The function returns `0` if there are no differences between the two strings (i.e. there are zero differences). If the returned number is lesser than or greater than `0` then the two strings are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Because `!==` compares the value *and* the type and `!=` implicitly converts the Strings to Integers.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you one link:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> If you compare **numerical** strings, each string is converted to a **number** ommiting all the leading zeroes and symbols (and the comparison performed numerically).

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
=== and !==
```

do strict matching. Whereas

```
== and !=
```

does not.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible always do strict comparisons.

`==` and `!=` do really weird things, for example in your case the both look like numbers, so PHP will compare the strings numerically (= try to convert them to integers and compare them)..

More weird examples in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php